# Whether and how to calculate adjusted r-squared in factor analysis?

Tags: r, regression, factor-analysis

I am using the `factanal` function in `R` to conduct factor analysis. Somebody told me that I need to use Adjusted $R^2$ to get more accurate results in factor analysis. But when I looked at the option of factor analysis, I couldn't find the way to do that. Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe the more general question is, are R2 and factor analysis related?

Comment: This question doesn't belong here, since there is no programming question. This should have been posted on CrossValidated instead. But the goodness of fit of factor analysis is usually measured by chi-square, not R-square, so your question doesn't make much sense.

Comment: So you are asking whether default factor loadings and the variance explained by a factor are biased?

Answer (score 3):

$R^2$ and adjusted  $R^2$ are measures of goodness of fit in regression.  $R^2$ never decreases when additional variables are added.  To have a measure that does not necessarily do that the adjusted  $R^2$ was devised.  Other measures used to pick a regression model from a set of potential models are $C_p$, AIC and BIC.  I agree with others that this does not seem to be a tool used in factor analysis and that is why it is not an option in the R routine for factor analysis. It could be that your friend made the comment thinking that you were talking about a regression problem.

Comment: Michael, can you clarify how this is related to factor analysis?

Comment: btw, you've hit 20+ upvotes for the second straight day. Wow! That's not easy on a relatively small-scale site like this one.

Comment: @Macro Thanks.  Regarding your question, the OP doesn't seem to know what R square is, or at least what the adjusted R square is.  I am giving background so that the OP could understand what the person might have meant had he or she been referring to regression rather than factor analysis.  But the only point i am making about factor analysis is the same as what others wrote in their comments, namely that the reason that the OP could not find adjusted R square in the R factor analysis routine is because adjusted R square is not relevant to factor analysis.